# On jquery.popover openEvent call function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call function on openEvent but it doesn't work. I'm using [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/kematzy/jquery-popover).

My code is mentioned below:

```
$("#verified_icon").popover({
                title: "",
                content: "You have a fanbase of over 1000 Amount of fans they have.",
                hideOnHTMLClick: false,
                openEvent: 'localhost/project/common_ctrl/update_popup_status',
                trigger: 'hover',
            });
            $("#verified_icon").popover('show');
```

anybody help me.........
thanks in advance

Comment: which plugin do you use?

Comment: I use jquery.popover plugin....
https://github.com/kematzy/jquery-popover

Comment: This looks odd to me : `openEvent:'localhost/project/common_ctrl/update_popup_status'`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your callback function obviously should follow the [rules for valid JavaScript variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: i will update the status in database that pop up pops there only once time.......

Comment: `openEvent:` will call a function. Where is that function in your javascript code?

Comment: u mean that's only call java-script function?

Comment: According to the documentation provided in your link, thats how it works. However, you can implement your logic in a callback function provided in `openEvent`. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to specify a http route in this parameter, which probably will not work.

According to the docs for the jquery plugin [kematzy/jquery-popover](https://github.com/kematzy/jquery-popover), you should specify a callback function in the  `openEvent` parameter. You can implement your desired logic within this function.